# geometry.getArea() versus getArea from ol/sphere

Tags: gis, openlayers-6

I am trying to understand the difference between:

1. polygon or multipolygon `getArea` ([documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon-Polygon.html#getArea))
2. `getArea` from `ol/sphere` ([documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html#.getArea))

The documentation of #1 reads:

> Return the area of the polygon on projected plane.

The documentation of #2 reads:

> Get the spherical area of a geometry. This is the area (in meters) assuming that polygon edges are segments of great circles on a sphere.

Can someone clarify this for me? I want to measure areas (application is agriculture / cadastre related) for [EPSG:2100](https://epsg.io/2100). If I understand correctly #1 should be used and not #2

Comment: In a local projection there would be very little difference between the two methods.  A local transverse mercator is usually accurate to better than 4 meters per km.  But in a global projection such as EPSG:3857 where Greenland looks as big as Africa you would always need the sphere method to get the true area.